# Read string from textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have the below code in WPF application.
It reads the strings from the serial port and displays in textbox.
I want to execute an operation according to the serial input.

This I'm thinking to do either by reading the string variable (RData) or by reading the textbox.text.

I've tried with if statements in the functions but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
    string RData;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        getPorts();
    }

    void getPorts()
    {
        String[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        comboBoxPorts.ItemsSource = ports;
    }

    private void buttonConnect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        serial.PortName = comboBoxPorts.Text;
        serial.BaudRate = 9600;
        serial.DataBits = 8;
        serial.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
        serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serial.ReadTimeout = -1;
        serial.WriteTimeout = -1;
        serial.Open();

        if (serial.IsOpen)
        {
            buttonConnect.IsEnabled = false;
            labelConState.Content = "Connected";
            labelConState.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green;

            serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recieve);
        }
    }

    private delegate void UpdateUiTextDelegate(string text);

    private void Recieve
        (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RData = serial.ReadExisting();

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(WriteData), RData);
    }

    private void WriteData(string text)
    {
        textBoxPrompt.Text += text;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the question (or problem)?

Comment: How can I get the text written in the textBoxPrompt to perform a task?

Comment: Have you tried to place a `break point` on this line `textBoxPrompt.Text += text;` and check if text parameter has the desired value ? Or maybe the function is not being hit at all ?

Comment: You need to tell us what is happening, what symptoms you are seeing etc. Like what @user3185569 suggested, place breakpoints, place it at various parts of this whole source codes, find out what is being executed, what is not. It is very hard for others to figure out what is going on, especially problems with serial ports, where results are heavily dependent on the hardware and actual data being transmitted.

Comment: Now say the serial input was `"2"`. The `textBoxPrompt` displays 2, and the variable `text` also has the value `2`. This is checked.
But now i want to do something like `if(textBoxPrompt.Text == "2"){//make label 1 green}`. This if condition doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Where do you place that if statement? Is that label that `labelConState` label you have mentioned in the question?

Comment: No it's a different label. I tried placing the if statement inside the `WriteData` and also inside `MainWindow`. But doesnt work.

Comment: Yup. Doesn't work either. I'm thinking of separating the serial reading and reading textbox into two threads. Will that work?

Answer (score -1):

You should set parity property of SerialPort.

Comment: I missunderstood your question. I tested your code above and it worked for me. I wrote if receive string "2", label color is changed to red and if condition worked. if(textBoxPrompt.Text == "2") { labelConState.Foreground == Brushes.Red;}

Comment: I worked for me once but then stopped working. Seems like it miss the if in the tread.
Inside what did you put the `if condition?`